# Column Visibility based on Report Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report which has a tablix within it.  What i would like to do is make certain columns visibility disappear depending upon a value in a parameter.

The parameter is called "Report Title" and the report titles which are available where the column should disappear are as follows:

- Cash Book Lite Settlement
- Cash Book Lite Trade
- Cash Book Lite Sett-Trade
- Cash Book Lite Settlement - Daily
- Cash Book Lite Trade - Daily
- Cash Book Lite Sett-Trade - Daily

I'm unsure of the syntax to do this.  I know the syntax below will work for one:

```
=IIF(Parameters!RPT_TITL_NME.Value = "Cash Book Lite Trade", TRUE, FALSE)
```

However what would the syntax be to include all of the above?

(This is not a multivalue parameter by the way)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IIF(Parameters!RPT_TITL_NME.Value = "..." OR Parameters!RPT.TITL_NME.Value = "..." OR ..., TRUE, FALSE)
```

Basically you're writing VisualBasic.NET here, so any VisualBasic.NET syntax should work.